# "Many of people" and "Many people"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When do we use "**Many of people**"? and When do we use "**Many people**"?

> Amusement park rides are stressful but also exhilarating and enjoyable to **many of people**. [Victim Assistance book](https://books.google.ae/books?id=J1-gpTQWjvMC&pg=PA67&dq=%22many%20of%20people%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22many%20of%20people%22&f=false)

> Mayor Bill de Blasio is urging other mayors to enroll as **many people** as possible in the ... [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2017/01/18/de-blasio-urges-mayors-enroll-many-people-possible-obamacare/96724508/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually don't think we ever say *many of people*, at least in standard English. *many of the people* is possible, but not *many of people*. So, we say either that or just *many people*.

Comment: Thank you, but it is used heavily in books [link](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Many+of+people%22)

Comment: Well, I'm currently reading the King James Bible. And they do use that type of grammar there. But I don't think it is part of standard English, however.

Comment: The King James Bible dates back to the same period as Shakespeare was writing (400 years ago!). Use it as a reference if you wish, but don't expect it to reflect English as it is used today! By the way, I like shorter ways of expressing things, and I would probably say ".. and enjoyable to many", or "... enjoyable for many", and "enrol as many as possible". The word "people" can easily be dropped in these examples. And note the spelling of 'enrol'!

Comment: @Shannak - A lot of those examples of "many of people" are actually part of "many of people's *nouns*", which is a different case, and a lot of the others appear to have been written by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "many of" immediately before a noun is not any common; it's ususual or rare.

You can say many people, a lot of people, lots of people.

However, you can use the phrase "many of" before a plural noun that comes after the definite article, or a demostrative/possessive pronoun, for examples, many of the people, many of these people, many of our people. You can also use the "many of" before an object pronoun, for example, many of us.

Answer (score 0):

I focus on the meaning of " of": part of total

For example, some of 100 boys shall be several boys among/out of 100 boys, so, in my idea, simply many in the "many of people" shall be not all the people but a lot of people. But in this case, some of the people here/there/in town--- shall be much more clear.